# Ckeditor's 4.5.4 with Word Count plugin Failing

Tags: ckeditor, word-count

I have installed [this](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) plugin for counting and restricting words submissions,but it has a bug when you have a text bigger than the 'maxCharCount:' at the clipboard, lets say my maxCharCount is set to 250 and I have a copied text of 300 words, if I past it in Ckeditor, it behaves correctly and the Notification plugin tells you you cant Paste, but if I copy again a smaller text like 220 words, and paste it again in ckeditor, the notification plugins again tells you the words to paste exceds the limit. 
It is also buggy when you try to pull an image from the Db browser, If you have done the Paste sequence prior to the image pasting, it doesnt allow.

The question should be...
Does anybody tried this plugin with success, if anybody did, is it possible to share the configuration you took to make it work?.
Im using the latest version of ckeditor as the latest version of wordcount.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want us to debug that plugin for you?

Comment: @AlfonsoML If you like so, SURE!